# Add Prefix to Email Notifications for Two Scripts under the same Job

Tags: jenkins

I'm attempting to clean up our Jenkins jobs as we have several scripts that could be run together instead of separately.  However, after combining some of them, it can be difficult to tell which passes/failures belong to certain scripts.

Here is an example of the email build log:

```
157 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 263.635 seconds
53 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 28.593 seconds
```

I simply want to prefix these with the related process, such as:

```
Unit Tests
157 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 263.635 seconds
End-to-end
53 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 28.593 seconds
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: what kind of plugin you are using now? Your requirement can be fixed by email ext plugin easily.

Comment: @Tim I'm using the Email-Ext Plugin v2.44, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin